# Add attribute to an Instance of an existing Class in Python 2

Tags: python, class, object, attributes, instance

In my data, I am getting two dictionaries at two different parts.  I created a Class object to combine the dictionaries into a single object.

In this example, `x` and `y` attributes are the Class dictionaries that are being assigned to `D_A_x` and `D_A_y` respectively.

**How can I add an attribute to a class instance that has already been created?**

```
class Class_Example:
    def __init__(self,x="NaN",y="NaN"):
        self.x = x; self.y = y
    def get_x(self,var): return(self.x[var])
    def get_y(self,var): return(self.y[var])

D_A = {}
D_A_x = {"a":1}
D_A["instance_1"] = Class_Example(x = D_A_x)
#D_A["instance_1"].get_x("a")

D_A_y = {"b":2}
D_A["instance_1"].__init__(y = D_A_y)

print D_A["instance_1"].get_x("a") #Doesn't work because it has been replaced.
```

I don't have access to `D_A_x` and `D_A_y` at the same time create the Class in one go.

I checked out this, but it didn't help in my situation: [Adding base class to existing object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042424/adding-base-class-to-existing-object-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its as you have already noticed, when you call `__init__()` for your `Class_Example` class , it overwrites the `x` and `y` values with the value passed in , and in the second time, since you do not send in anything for `x`, it uses the default `"NaN"` string .

You should not call `__init__()` again, you can simply set the `y` attribute. Example -

```
D_A["instance_1"].y = D_A_y
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do: `D_A['instance_1'].y = D_A_y`?