# Add a mixin to python enum after it's created?

Tags: python, enums, mixins, metaclass

### The Problem

Suppose I have an enum defined:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Foo(Enum):
   DAVE_GROHL = auto()
   MR_T = auto()
```

and I want to extend this class with specific methods **only** (ie, no new enum members):

```
class MixinFoo(Foo):
   def catch_phrase(self):
      if self is Foo.MR_T:
         return "I pity da foo!"
      else:
         return "There goes my hero!"
```

This will fail with `TypeError`, since by design enum's can't be extended once members have been defined. Python enum allows you to do this in the other direction (ie: define mixin with no members and subclass the mixin to add members), but in my specific use case, defining `MixinFoo` before `Foo` to use as a base class is not an option (eg: `Foo` is defined in another module and I don't want to recreate it or modify that module's code).

### What I've considered so far:

Tweaking the `EnumMeta`. `EnumMeta` checks for existing members in the base class in the `__prepare__` method, so overriding this method and deferring the check in a new metaclass could work. Unfortunately, `EnumMeta` checks for existing members in several other functions, and redefining all those functions seems like bad practice in general (lots of duplicated code).

Adding functions after the fact. I know it's possible to do something like:

```
def catch_phrase(self):
   ...

Foo.catch_phrase = catch_phrase
```

and while this might work, there are some significant disadvantages that I would like to avoid (eg: very cumbersome for a large number of functions, static/class methods, properties of normal class definition might be difficult to implement)

Solving the problem with composition over inheritance:

```
class FooWrapper():
   def __init__(self, foo):
      self._foo = foo

   def catch_phrase(self):
      ...
```

While this is possible, I'm not a huge fan of this method.

### Some Related Questions:

Why does `EnumMeta` have checks for existing members outside of `__prepare__`? From a design perspective, this seems to not only be redundant, but also makes it unnecessarily difficult to extend the `EnumMeta` as in my case. I understand the rationale behind not allowing extension of enums with more members, but mixins were obviously considered in the design of the enum library. Was this an oversight in the design of the enum? Was it considered and rejected? Is it intentional for some reason?

Furthermore, one of the checks for existing members is buried in the `_EnumDict` class, which is not accessible, so I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible without recreating a fairly substantial portion of the enum library.

The overall intent is that I have a common enum where the members are known and fixed, but the use case and methods are application specific (ie, different applications that use `Foo` would have different greetings and possibly other functions to add, but no application would need to add other `Foo`s).

Comment: I will likely come back here later for a full answer, but from a first peek you will need to recreate `Foo` monkeypatch its definition in the place it is defined. That is dangerous because the reliability of your Foo members won't be the same objects as the original Foo members and any module that have imported Foo before you do the monkeypatch will fail in detecting your passed Foo members in.

Comment: "Enum" is not the most friendly or simpler of Python moduels in the stdlib to fiddle with, but sometimes using the "Enum" tag summons their author himself to the question. Just wait and see :-).

Comment: @jsbueno That's kinda what I was hoping for XD. I know he's very active on SO enum questions, and recall in the past he has strongly recommended against tweaking the EnumMeta, but it seems a shame (and bad software design) to re-create that wheel.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my enum catch filter was broken.  :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1: assign new methods to existing Enum

Does simply assigning a method to `Foo` works?

Like in `Foo.catch = lambda self=None: print(Foo if self is None else "MR_T" if self is Foo.MR_T else "Ka-bong")`

If not, why? It does behave, for all purposes as a method would, and "self" is filled with the "Foo" member if the method is called from the member.

If you want to benefit from Python's mechanism for creating classes and the "class" statement block syntax, this is easily feasible with a "pseudo" metaclass: a callable that will take in the contents of the class body, along with the name and bases - it can them just add the newly created methods and attributes to the existing Enum class:

```
def EnumMixinExtender(name, bases, ns):
    original = bases[0]
    for k, v in ns.items():
        setattr(original, k, v)
    return original
```

This will allow you to extend `Foo` in place with

```
class MixinFoo(Foo, metaclass=EnumMixinExtender):
   def catch_phrase(self=None):
        ...
```

With this option, `MixinFoo is Foo` and `MixinFoo.member1 is Foo.member1`: the Foo class is monkey patched in place - no need to care about import order: everyone using "Foo" can use "catch_phrase".

## Option 2 - MixinFoo != Foo:

If one must preserve a distinct `Foo` class and need that `Foo.member1 is not MixinFoo.member1` asserts True - the way out, still using a pseudo-metaclass is to invert things, and create a copy of `Foo` that would derive from the new class-members defined in the Mixin. The metaclass code just does that in the reversed order, so that the Enum class comes later into the mix.

```
def ReverseMixinAdder(name, bases, ns):
    pre_bases = tuple(base for base in bases if not isinstance(base, enum.EnumMeta))
    pos_bases = tuple(base for base in bases if isinstance(base, enum.EnumMeta))

    new_mixin = type(f"{name}_mixin", pre_bases, ns)
    member_space = {}
    for base in pos_bases:
        member_space |= {k: v.value for k, v in base.__members__.items()}
    new_enum = Enum(name, member_space, type=new_mixin )
    return new_enum
```

Just use that as the metaclas, like above, and you get an independent "MixinFoo" class, that can be passed around and used independent from Foo. The drawback is that not only its members "are not" Foo members, just copies, but MixinFoo won't be a subclass or otherwise related to Foo at all.

(btw, just ignore the mechanisms allowing one to merge more than one Enum if you won't use them. I had not tested that part either)

## Option 3 - MixinFoo != Foo, but issubclass(MixinFoo, Foo):

If one must have MixinFoo as a distinct class from Foo and still have `MixinFoo.member1 is Foo.member1` and `issubclass(MixinFoo, Foo)` to assert True,

Well... looking into the traceback when one tries to extend an Enum with mixin methods we have:

```
    565                 if issubclass(base, Enum) and base._member_names_:
--> 566                     raise TypeError(
```

Sure this is an implementation detail - but all EnumMeta checks at this point is... *member_names* - which happens to be assignable.

If one simply assigns a falsey value to "Foo.*member_names*", it can be subclassed, with extra mixin methods and ordinary attributes at will. The `._member_names_` can be restored afterwards.

Doing this, these assertions hold: `FooMixin.member1 is Foo.member1`, `FooMixin is not Foo`, `issubclass(FooMixin, Foo)`. However, the new methods can not be called directly on the members - that is, in the previous two options one can do `FooMixin.member1.catch_phrase()`, while under this, as the member enum keeps the class `Foo` which does not have the new method, that does not work. (The workaround is `FooMixin.catch_phrase(FooMixin.member1`) .

If one wants this last part to work, Foo.members can have their `__class__` attribute updated to `FooMixin` - and it will work, but then the original `Foo.members` are updated inplace as well.

I have the intuition this final form is what you are really asking for here -

```
class MetaMixinEnum(enum.EnumMeta):
    registry = {}

    @classmethod
    def _get_enum(mcls, bases):
        enum_index, member_names = next((i, base._member_names_) for i, base in enumerate(bases) if issubclass(base, Enum))
        return bases[enum_index], member_names

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(mcls, name, bases):
        base_enum, member_names = mcls._get_enum(bases)
        mcls.registry[base_enum] = member_names
        base_enum._member_names_ = []
        return super().__prepare__(name, bases)

    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, ns):
        base_enum, _  = mcls._get_enum(bases)
        try:
            new_cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, ns)
        finally:
            member_names = base_enum._member_names_ = mcls.registry[base_enum]
        new_cls._member_names_ = member_names[:]
        for name in member_names:
            setattr(getattr(new_cls, name), "__class__", new_cls)
        return new_cls


class FooMixin(Foo, metaclass=MetaMixinEnum):
    def catch_phrase(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, this does technically work and I have considered it as an option, I just don't think it's ideal for my specific use case. Foo is part of a module that I want users to be able to extend with functionality, and I see this as being a little too user-unfriendly (eg, the reliability issues you mentioned, cumbersome if there are a lot of methods to add).

Comment: I did not mention any "reliability issues" for this case: this changes "Foo" process-wide.

Comment: (just for context for 3rd party readers: the 2 comments above where written when the answer was a stub containing the first 3 paragraphs from the current content)

Answer (score 3):

## Option 4 - issubclass(Foo, MixinFoo)

Building on @jsbueno's with inspiration from an answer from @l4mpi in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042424/adding-base-class-to-existing-object-in-python). Here we monkeypatch `Foo` such that it is a subclass of `MixinFoo`, as would be the case for a typical Enum mixin. We simply add `MixinFoo` to `Foo`'s bases:

```py
class Foo(Enum):
   ...

class MixinFoo(Enum):
   def catch_phrase(self):
      ...

Foo.__bases__ = (MixinFoo, ) + Foo.__bases__

for foo in Foo:
   foo.catch_phrase()
```

Comment: oh...that was easy. Indeed, TIL I learned `__bases__` is writable - I did not think it was.

Comment: @jsbueno: Heh -- I knew it was, but it's easy to forget since it is done so rarely!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does `EnumMeta` have checks for existing members outside of `__prepare__`?

Good question.  It no longer does (as of 3.11).

> Furthermore, one of the checks for existing members is buried in the `_EnumDict` class

No, the check in `_EnumDict` is for members already defined *in that enum*:

```
class Foo(Enum):
    BAR = 1
    BAR = 1 # this errors out because of _EnumDict
```

---

I like your **Option 4** -- but of course, it should be a [decorator](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-decorator):

```
def add_methods_to(cls):
    def insert_class(scls):
        cls.__bases__ = (scls, ) + cls.__bases__
        return scls
    return insert_class
```

and in action:

```
@add_methods_to(Foo)
class MixinFoo:             # mix-in class does not need to be an enum
    def catch_phrase(self):
        return 'blah blah'
```

Comment: Regarding mix-in class not needing to be an Enum: This is probably a force of habit I picked up from the docs, as all the mix-in examples there (Foo, OrderedEnum, DuplicateFree, etc) subclass Enum. At the very least I find this useful to a) Suppress any "unresolved attribute references" that code inspectors may throw and b) make it obvious that the class is intended to be mixed-in to an Enum (less relevant in the decorator/properly documented code case). Is there something I'm missing for the examples in the docs?

Comment: @TonyGweesip: Nope, just wanted to remind folks that's it's not necessary.  :-)  Most of the examples in the docs are meant for single-inheritance chains: `Enum` -> `OrderedEnum` -> `MyEnumThatIsOrdered` -- but that is not a mix-in case.

Comment: Not sure if this was intentional or just a typo, but returning `cls` from `insert_class` makes `MixinFoo` an alias of `Foo` (`MixinFoo is Foo`), which is a little more strict that the original intent of having `Foo` be a subclass of `MixinFoo`. Returning `scls` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @TonyGweesip: Yup, you're right.  Guess I'm not used to inheriting backwards.  ;-)